# Срабатывавет catch, не могу понять почему

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

Делаю проверку [express-validator](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator) введеных пользователем данных. Отдельно проверяю аватар пользователя. Срабатывает валидатор, выводит ошибки что я не одного поля не ввел:

```
 {
    "err": [
        {
            "location": "body",
            "param": "user_name",
            "msg": "Invalid value"
        },
        {
            "location": "body",
            "param": "user_name",
            "msg": "Invalid value"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Почему срабатывает `catch`, где я ошибся?
Сам код:

```
import upload from'../config/multer.config.js';
import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator/check';

const validatorSignup = [
    check('user_name').exists().isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 }),
    ...
];

router.post('/add', validatorSignup, (req, res) => {
try {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                err: err
            });
        }
    })
    const error = validationResult(req);
    if (!error.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            err: error.array()
        });
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: В `catch` выведите ошибку `console.log(err)`.

Comment: Пишет `validatorSignup is not a function`. Тогда вопрос, как мне обьеденить мои `upload` и `validatorSignup`? Чтобы проверял и то и то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я может чего-то не понимаю, но у вас `validatorSignup` - массив, а вызываете вы его как функцию:

```
validatorSignup(req, res, (err) => { // проверка введеных полей 
    [....]
})
```

Надо так:

```
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(expressValidator());

const validatorSignup = function (req, res, next) {
    req.check('user_name').exists().isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 });
    [...]

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            err: errors
        });
    }

    next();
};

router.post('/add', validatorSignup, (req, res) => {
    [...]
});
```

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку, но теперь у меня не работает проверка полей, что я не так делаю?

Comment: @MegaRoks обновил ответ.

Comment: Я запутался основательно, у меня пробелма с добавлением `upload`. В чем заключается моя ошибка?

Comment: @MegaRoks лучше отдельным вопросом.